# Popover inside jQuery dataTables does not work after Page changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Am using a JQUERY Datatable and Webui Popover plugin on my page. The popover actually assigned for an element in

```
<small style=" color: #10336B;"  class='codedescription'  
data-title="My Title" data-content='My Dynamic Content'><b>CODE
```

and here the Popover initialisation

```
$('.codedescription').webuiPopover({ closeable: false, trigger: 'hover', title: '', content: '', delay: { show: null, hide: 300} });
```

Its working fine when the first page or just after the Datatable being binded. But if we move to another page on the datatable or after the page changed, the popover stopped working. Only the first time initialised popovers worked.

So I tried reinitialising the popover plugin at the Datatable page change event as follows.

```
$('#tbl_main').on('page.dt', function () {
    alert(55);
    $('.codedescription').webuiPopover({ closeable: false, trigger: 'hover', title: '', content: '', delay: { show: null, hide: 300} });
});
```

But when ever the page changes alert shows, but the popovers not showing in any pages other than the first page. What is making the popovers to not work after the page changes in JQUERY Datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `draw.dt` event. [**`page.dt`**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) is triggered when the table's paging is updated, [**`draw.dt`**](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw) is triggered when the dataTable has *completed a draw*.

```js
$('#tbl_main').on('draw.dt', function () {
   ...
});
```